# Undefined Index, but index exists

Tags: php, exception, indexing, undefined

$cart is an array with different indexes. Everything worked out fine, until I added one index ('cvariation'). As you can see I gave out the $cart- array above, to check if it is empty. But it is not. I don't get the mistake I made. Can someone please help me?

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $cartcount; $i++)
{
    var_dump($cart);
    $innerarray[] = $cart[$i];
    $quantity = $innerarray['quantity'];
    $title = $innerarray['articleTitle'];
    $description = $innerarray['articleDescription'];
    $price = $innerarray['articlePrice'];
    $articlenumber = $innerarray['articleNumber'];
    $tax = $innerarray['tax'];
    $taxvalue = $innerarray['taxvalue'];
    $cvariation = $innerarray['cvariation'];
```

[image]

Comment: Can we see more of your code? where's `$cartcount`

Comment: Are you sure about that? If you use `$innerarray[]`, you create a new element at the end of `$innerarray`, with a numeric index. Accessing `$innerarray['quantity']` does not access anything within that recently attached item

Comment: The notice says `quantity` is the undefined index (or the first one, not clear if there”s similar messages after that) - but that should not have changed because you added something that tries to access the index `cvariation`, that notice should have been there before already.

Comment: @Isaac I think it is irrelevant. For you to understand, this function is for a shop system. So this for loop is just there to repeat this action for every 'article'. $cartcout is just a count of the 'articles' in the 'shopping cart' ($cartcount = count($cart);).

Comment: @04FS no, everything was fine. That is the problem I don't understand.

Comment: So everything becomes fine again then, if you simply comment out that single line `$cvariation = $innerarray['cvariation'];` now …? That is very hard to believe.

Comment: @NicoHaase every index will be noticed. I dumped $innerarray, and the indexes were not numeric.

Comment: @04FS Unfortunally it does not. I don't get this. i promise you, everything was fine.

Comment: _“I dumped $innerarray, and the indexes were not numeric”_ - that sounds impossible as well, same as pretty much the rest of what you stated so far. But it does not make much sense that we keep guessing - provide a proper [mcve] that shows the problem, please. (You can use var_export to create a code representation of your $cart array, to easily create a reduced example that allows to properly test this.)

Comment: @JUH do you have any dump of `$innerarray` to share with us? Are you really sure that `$innerarray['quantity']` exists after writing the above code? Are you sure that you're not mixing that up with `$innerarray[0]['quantity']`, which indeed is available according to the image you've shared?

Comment: `$innerarray` is a 2-dimensional array. The first dimension has numeric indexes, the second dimension has named indexes. You're looking for `cvariation` in the first dimension, not the second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$innerarray[] = $cart[$i];
```

makes `$innerarray` a 2-dimensional array, just like `$cart`. It looks like you just wanted `$innerarray` to be the current element of the iteration, so that should be:

```
$innerarray = $cart[$i];
```